# Pesquisar algo numa lista e dizer se existe ou não - Apresentar Valor, e soma de quantidade

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde, qual é a maneira mais fácil de fazer uma lista em que contém vários items, por exemplo carne, peixe, pao etc, e a partir da váriavel $_GET saber se o produto existe ou não ? tentei criar um array e fazer com array_key_exist mas não estou a conseguir. obrigado

Comment: Esses produtos estão num base de dados? MySql por exemplo

Comment: é um exercicio simples que estou a tentar fazer, estou a colocar os produtos num array, e quero quando faço...php?leite/ Ele diga se o leite existe no array ou nao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça assim então:

```
$produtos = array(
    'Leite' => array(
        'preco' => 1.5,
    ),
    'Chocolate' => array(
        'preco' => 10,
    ),
    'Pão' => array(
        'preco' => 3.5,
    ),
    'Sal' => array(
        'preco' => 0.5,
    ),
);
// EX: aceda a www.seusite.com?produto=Leite&quantidade=5 e depois:
if(isset($_GET['produto'])) {
    echo 'Preço por unidade: ' .$produtos[$_GET['produto']]['preco']. '<br>';
    if(isset($_GET['quantidade'])) {
        echo 'Preço total: ' .$produtos[$_GET['produto']]['preco']*$_GET['quantidade'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'Preço total: ' .$produtos[$_GET['produto']]['preco'];
    }
}
else {
    echo 'Produto indefinido';
}
```

Comment: deu certo! Era mesmo isso que eu precisava ! Obrigado :)

Comment: De nada @MarioCaeiro, se resolveu mesmo pode/deve aceitar a resposta. Ainda bem que resolveu

Comment: Miguel, se eu quisesse fazer de outra maneira, caso o produto fosse encontrado, apresentaria o preço, por exemplo php?/produto=Leite, output: Leite 1.90 ?

Comment: Ha vou editar a resposta para isso, dê-me 2 mins

Comment: Ok vou esperar a edição! obrigado !

Comment: Feito @MarioCaeiro

Comment: Não querendo abusar, daria para fazer a soma em caso de colocar algo do genero no url .php?/produto=Leite&Quantidade=5 e apresentar neste caso 5x o 'preco'?

Comment: 2 mins @MarioCaeiro

Comment: Feito @MarioCaeiro , aceda por ex a `aceda a www.seusite.com?produto=Leite&quantidade=5`

Comment: Miguel, muito obrigado pela ajuda, estou dando os meus primeiros passos em php e a tua ajuda foi preciosa e muito directa, obrigado por partilhares o teu conhecimento comigo e o teu tempo! um grande abraço

Comment: Sem problema @MarioCaeiro, ainda bem que ajudei. Pedia-lhe que editasse a pergunta agora de acordo com os desenvolvimentos que tivemos. Acresentar isto da multiplicação e quantidade sff, para que quem tiver a mesma duvida consiga ver alguma coerência de perguntas/respostas

Comment: está a dizer para adicionar tags com quantidade multiplicação etc? desculpe também estou no stackoverflow à pouco tempo

Comment: Não não, adicionar à pergunta que quer também preço, quantidade e multiplicação... Tudo o que foi desenvolvido que não está lá... As tags estão bem @MarioCaeiro

Answer (score 1):

Se quer fazer na variável $_GET, considere adicionar vários itens no mesmo indice do parâmetro `GET`.

Veja:

```
url?itens[]=pão&itens[]=leite&itens[]=ovo
```

No PHP isso retornaria:

```
 print_r($_GET['itens']); // ["pão", "leite", "ovo"]
```

Para a url ficar da maneira espeficada no comentário, você precisa declarar o formulário assim:

```
 <input type="text" name="itens[]" value="ovo" />
 <input type="text" name="itens[]" value="pão" />
```

Para verificar, basta apenas guardar uma lista de valores esperados e compare assim:

```
 $valores = $_GET['itens'];

 ksort($valores);

 $obrigatorios = ['leite', 'ovo', 'pão']

 var_dump($valores === $obrigatorios);
```

Outra maneira de fazer a verificação seria usando a função `array_intersect`:

```
count(array_intersect($obrigatorios, $valores)) > 0
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda !